# Why my AJAX didn't work and been blocked by CORS after I deployed my website online?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I made an AJAX comments board in Laravel. It works fine in localhost but didn't work on the web.

The console log said it was blocked by CORS policy.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GH0J.jpg

And return status '302 found'.

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCVRg.jpg

I don't know how to fixed it.
Here's my code:

**javescript**:

```
$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});

$.post(  "/savecomment",
      {
    content:$("#content").val(),
    cComment:$("#commentText").val(),
    cRating:$("#cRating").val(),
    pNo:$("#pNo").val(),
    pName:$("#pName").val(),
    production_id:$("#production_id").val()
    },
    function(data){
        let cmt=JSON.parse(data); 
        .
        .
        .
    });
```

**route**:

```
Route::post('/savecomment/', 'HikingController@saveComment');
```

**controller**:

```
public function saveComment(Requset $request)
{


       .
       .
       .

    echo json_encode(array(
        'id' => $c->id,
        'uName' => $c->uName,
        'cTime' => $c->cTime,
        'uAvatar' => $c->uAvatar,
        'cRating' => $c->cRating,
        'cComment' => $c->cComment,
        'production_id' => $c->production_id,
        'avgRating' => $c->calRating(request('pNo')),
        'commentCount' => $c->getAll(request('pNo'))->count(),
}
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by modifying your route

```
Route::post('/savecomment', 'HikingController@saveComment');
```

As post method need same URL so you have to pass same URI as they are here you passed

```
$.post(  "/savecomment", .... )
```

Without `/` and your route has `/` so change one of them

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No worries. That's your wish. But I had same problem and that was fixed by this way.  So I shared with you :)

Comment: Thank you:) I will try that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from a security mechanism that browsers implement called the same-origin policy.

The same-origin policy fights one of the most common cyber attacks out there: cross-site request forgery.

**Add these header setting to the php file that your Ajax is accessing**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

//then do your staff below
```

Read about **same-origin policy**

Comment: Yes the controller that serves the request to the Ajax call

Comment: Not a good idea to add headers like this, what about other controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors,
It is supported officially by Laravel also exists in Laravel initial dependencies from version 7.

Comment: Why it is blocked by cors? Aren't they in the same domain?

Comment: As console log saying, No `ACAO` header is present in the requested resource. you can add it to all of responses' header using a middleware or use mentioned library to doing so with more options.